# Grails 2.3.4 Database View as Domain Class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to use database view as domain class, following steps from Burt Beckwith slide.

http://www.slideshare.net/gr8conf/gorm-burt-beckwith2011

I have defined the config class:

```
configClass = 'sfgroups.DdlFilterConfiguration'
```

package sfgroups

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration

class DdlFilterConfiguration extends GrailsAnnotationConfiguration  {
    private static final String[] IGNORED_NAMES={"v_fullname"}

    private boolean isIgnored(String command){
        command=command.toLowerCase()

        for( String table : IGNORED_NAMES ){
            if( command.startsWith("create table " + table + " ") ||
                command.startsWith("alter table " + table + " ") ||
                command.startsWith("drop table " + table + " ") ||
                command.startsWith("drop table if exists " + table + " ")   ){
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

Domain class

```
package com.sfg

class FullName {

    String firstname
    String lastname

    static mapping = {
        table = 'v_fullname'     
    }
}
```

When I run the application its giving this error message.

```
 ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [com.sfg.FullName]:  No such property: table for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
Message: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [com.sfg.FullName]:  No such property: table for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
```

how can I fix this startup error?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `=` sign from your mapping [doc](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Database%20Mapping/table.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use

```
  static mapping = {
            table 'v_fullname'     
        }
```

instead of

```
static mapping = {
        table = 'v_fullname'     
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use this, need to add  version false

```
static mapping = {
        table  'v_fullname'
        version false
    }
```